# Any C# sample code accessing GitHub API?

Tags: c#, .net, github, github-api

I need a sample code to login GitHub and request any method with authentication. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [GitHub API Libraries](http://develop.github.com/p/libraries.html) page links to the official [octokit.net](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net) project which has samples in its repository.

Answer (score 3):

[GitHubSharp](https://github.com/erikzaadi/GithubSharp) can help you, just look at the samples and then the code.